# Select inner edge of solidified mesh

Tags: modeling, edges, selection-tools

I am following [this](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-beer-blender/) tutorial, but I just can't get past step 10. No matter what I try I cannot select inner vertices.

Here is my mesh after hitting A-KEY, it looks like the inner edges are not selected. They are not bright orange like the outer edges even after doing a select-all.

[image]

Blender ver: 2.68

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: To select the generated vertices, first you need to apply the solidify modifier.

Comment: It won't likely affect this situation, but you might want to update to the latest blender version (2.76 at the time of writing)

Comment: @Denis, that was it!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to apply the **Solidify** modifier. This will generate the inner vertices.

Or you can do this without modifiers. Select your mesh, go into Edit mode. Select all the vertices you'd like to solidify and do one of the following:

- hit <kbd>Space</kbd>, then type "Solidufy";
- or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *Solidify*.

After execution of the operation you can adjust the thickness either pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> or opening bottom of the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, where 'Last Operator' scroll located.

Comment: Note that you would like to do this *instead* of adding modifier, so it should be deleted if it's already present.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure "on cage" is selected in Solidify modifier.

Using blender 3.6.2

[image]